# Rails nested_form find element added

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form in a form, which on clicking on a button adds a bunch of fields for the user to complete.

At the moment, when the user clicks on it, I sum to a variable that tracks the amount of fields added.
On the bunch of things added I add a button to remove them (a link_to_remove from the nested_form gem). I want to have an action on click on the remove button, BUT for some reason it is not activating it.

Here's the code on the view:

```
= f.fields_for :guests do |guest_form|
  (...)
  = guest_form.link_to_remove t('actions.delete'), class: 'flex button button-general btn red-button delete-client-button form-rate delete-room-button', method: 'get'

= f.link_to_add ((fa_stacked_icon "plus", base: "circle-thin", class: 'button-icon') + t('reservations.new.add_client')), :guests, class: 'button btn button-general green-button add-button new-client-button'
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$('.delete-client-button').click(function() {
  do something...
});
```

But it is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delegate the element

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete-client-button', function() {
  do something...
});
```

Comment: Perfect, simple solution.